# How to run a script upon IP change

Tags: debian, networking, dhcp, network-interface

My Debian machine is currently part of my home LAN, behind the ISP box which handles all network related activities (DHCP, firewalling, telephony, IPTV, ...). A classical case of residential home network.

I plan to soon move the server to a switch between the fiber converter (fiber in, RJ45 out) and the ISP box - and configure it to receive my Internet public IP address via DHCP from the ISP.

My ISP unfortunately forces a change of this address from time to time (in order to provide a "professional service" of a fixed IP for a fee). I wrote a script which checks my IP address as seen on Internet and modifies the DNS entry of my external-facing name in case of mismatch.

I can run this script periodically via `cron` but it would be more interesting to trigger it when the `eth0` IP changes (which will happen when the ISP pushes a new address "to its box", which is actually now my server).

**Is there such a a mechanism available (actions to do upon a change of the IP address)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a Network Manager dispatcher script to run a script when the interface comes up or down, which it will do when the ISP changes your IP address (it'll drop your connection then bring it back up with a new one).

Have a look at the files in `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/`.  In mine there is a simple script `20-chrony` which makes a good template:

```
#!/bin/sh
# This is a NetworkManager dispatcher script for chronyd to set its NTP sources
# online/offline when a default route is configured/removed on the system.

export LC_ALL=C

if [ "$2" = "up" ]; then
        /sbin/ip route list dev "$1" | grep -q '^default' &&
                /usr/bin/chronyc -a online > /dev/null 2>&1
fi

if [ "$2" = "down" ]; then
        /sbin/ip route list | grep -q '^default' ||
                /usr/bin/chronyc -a offline > /dev/null 2>&1
fi

exit 0
```

You can adapt the two `if` statements to work with your scripts, or if your scripts only needs to run when the interface comes up, just modify the first `if` and remove the second.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a system with the dbus-monitor(1) tool, you can start this program as a daemon so it can monitor for interface address changes.  Not sure which message it is but something like:

```
dbus-monitor 'some-filtering-expression' |
while read -r line; do
    xargs /path/to/your/script "${line"}
done
```

You could also let dbus-monitor free-run (with no filters) to watch what happens when your network connection comes up.